# clear an array of ranges using a single line of code

Tags: vba, excel

i have made global string constants for ranges.

```
Global Const Graph_Cl As String = "G2:G13"
Global Const Graph_Vl As String = "I2:I13"
Global Const Graph_VlS As String = "L2:L13"
```

i want to clear these ranges using a single line of code.

```
With wkDataToUse
    .Range(Graph_Cl, Graph_Vl, Graph_VlS).ClearContents
End With
```

but i get error:

```
"Wrong no of arguments or invalid property assignment!"
```

i even tried this:

```
With wkDataToUse
    .Range(Array(Graph_Cl, Graph_Vl, Graph_VlS)).ClearContents
End With
```

OR

```
With wkDataToUse
    .Range([{Graph_Cl, Graph_Vl, Graph_VlS}]).ClearContents
End With
```

how can i clear all the ranges in one line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass multiple range addresses you need the comma delimited string format: `"a:b,c:d,e:f"` so you can;

```
.Range(Graph_Cl & "," & Graph_Vl & "," & Graph_VlS).ClearContents
```

You could also;

```
Union(.Range(Graph_Cl), .Range(Graph_Vl), .Range(Graph_VlS)).ClearContents
```